# How to Add Another Physical Drive to Adaptec maxView RAID6 Logical Drive

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, raid6, adaptec

I have an ASR71605.  I've added another drive to the controller which shows up in max view as ready.  The logical drive is RAID 6 with 5 drives in it now. I'm adding this additional drive which is identical to the other 5. (same brand, same model, same size, 512k just like the other ones. The new drive is initialized

When I select the logical drive and choose expand, I choose RAID 6 again, and then on the next screen add the additional drive and then click next. On the next screen the manual says that I should be able to set the size, but it just says "New Size" without anywhere to enter anything and there is no next button or even cancel. I've tried in all supported browsers.

Also I've tried this command line:

sudo /usr/StorMan/arcconf modify 1 FROM 0 TO max 6 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7 0 9 0 8

which I understand from the docs to mean on controller 1, logical drive 0, change the size to max, raid 6 and then a list of channel and device id in pairs. All on are on channel 0 and start at 4 and go to 9. 8 is the one being added.

It tells me:

The requested operation cannot be performed as one or more physical devices are not part of logical device.

I'm at a loss.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else has this issue like I and the OP did, here is how I was able to get the expansion to work.  I have a ASR81605, so I'm not sure if it is the same with the 7 series, but the MaxView web interface has the exact same issue and the command line has the exact same error.  Also, I'm expanding a RAID 5, but hopefully this will work for everyone.

After fighting with this for hours, I finally found the latest (as of 07/04/2020) MaxView Storage Manager download for Windows x64 at https://adaptec.com/en-us/speed/raid/storage_manager/msm_windows_x64_v3_04_23699_zip.php.  You should probably search for the latest version as they may eventually fix the web version too.
Once I downloaded this update and installed it, the MaxView web interface is still broken in the same way, but amazingly I was able to start the expansion with the command line.

This exact arcconf.exe command that failed in the old version now successfully completed in version 3.04.23699 dated 01/27/2020:

```
arcconf modify 1 from 0 to MAX 5 0 8 0 9 0 10 0 11 0 12 0 13 0 14 0 24 0 25
```

ID's 8-14 were the original and 24 and 25 were added.  Once the command completed, the MaxView web interface should the migration/expansion task running.

Comment: Wow, I have stepped on the same rake as well, but the fresh version of Storage Manager ( https://download.adaptec.com/raid/storage_manager/msm_linux_x64_v2_05_22932.tgz) works perfectly. :-)